# Why smaller filter's parameter has to multiply channel twice

Tags: computer-vision

I was reading the cs231 class notes(http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks) 
and here is where my question is from:

If we suppose that all the volumes have C channels, then it can be seen that the single 7x7 CONV layer would contain C×(7×7×C)=49C^2 parameters, while the three 3x3 CONV layers would only contain 3×(C×(3×3×C))=27C^2 parameters.

But why it is not (7 * 7 * C) and (3 * 3 * C)? The filter should have same channel size of the input. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Each filter is working on C channels so it has NxNxC parameters. In case of N=7 you get 7x7xC.

After using this filter you get only one output channel of size Width x Height.

Therefore in order to get C channels at the output you need to use C filters.

C(filters) * N(Filter Width) * N(Filter Height) * C(Number of channels the filters is working on, i.e the number of channels in the input layer)

Comment: Thank you very much Amitay! I think that is what I was looking for!